# How can I pipe to a PowerShell script residing in a path with spaces?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, powershell-7.3

I wrote a PowerShell script that's accepting input from the pipeline plus some parameters.

Now, when I want to call the script from another directory, the following doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem | 'D:\My Documents\PowerShell\My-Script.ps1' -MyParam 1 -OtherParam 'Test'
```

How do I call a PowerShell script residing at a path having spaces from another directory with parameters and pipeline input?

Comment: Use the call operator `| & 'D:\My Documents\PowerShell\....`

Comment: In short: An executable path that is _quoted_ or contains _variable references_ must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Solution and reasoning of the other issue might be the same, but the _question_ is completely different. I'm pretty sure that no-one searching for a question like mine will _ever_ find the other answer. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:

```
Get-ChildItem | & "D:\My Documents\PowerShell\My-Script.ps1" -MyParam 1 - 
OtherParam 'Test'
```